Error: Cannot sign for this input with the key in BitcoinJS transaction
I'm trying to create and sign a Bitcoin transaction using BitcoinJS on the testnet. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to sign the transaction:
Error: Can not sign for this input with the key 03ac517991619c9413d3f886f62feb41eea6c571c7ab3e3f61ef770f63667dd94f

Below is my code:
import * as bitcoin from "bitcoinjs-lib";
import ECPairFactory from 'ecpair';
import ecc from '@bitcoinerlab/secp256k1';

bitcoin.initEccLib(ecc)
const ECPair = ECPairFactory(ecc);


const network = bitcoin.networks.testnet

async function createTransaction(
    privateKeyWIF: string,
    previousTxid: string,
    receiverAddress: string,
    previousHex: string
) {

    const keyPair = ECPair.fromWIF(privateKeyWIF, network);


    const txb = new bitcoin.Psbt({ network });

    txb.setVersion(2);
    txb.setLocktime(0);

    txb.addInput({
        hash: previousTxid,
        index: 0,
        nonWitnessUtxo: Buffer.from(previousHex, 'hex'),
    });

    txb.addOutput({
        script: Buffer.from(receiverAddress, 'hex'),
        value: 200,
    }); // Sending 0.000002 BTC


    txb.signInput(0, keyPair);
    txb.finalizeAllInputs();

    const tx = txb.extractTransaction();
    return tx.toHex();
}


const main = () => {
    const privateKeyWIF = "..." // my WIF private from UniSat wallet
    const previousTxid = '1e1f8daf5b1c520dbe251e4919d84e105f1a9ac3446e563998e0fca8871c250c'
    const receiver = 'tb1pfjvvn8x9fy5c5ppzrq729tyhu04pneyumukvmnqw78vwugpyatgq5yvxlw'
    const previosHex = '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'

    createTransaction(privateKeyWIF, previousTxid, receiver, previosHex)
        .then((transactionHex) => {
            console.log('Transaction Hex:', transactionHex);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
        });
}

main()


One problem I see immediately is that you're parsing an address as a hexadecimal string.
